# Tensor perturbation of energy-momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, perturbation-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I encounter a problem regarding the tensor perturbation of energy momentum tensor. Recently, I am doing a tensor perturbation of Einstein-Hilbert action with some matter terms. My approach is that: Suppose we want to find out the gravitational waves in FRW metric, we can perturb this metric as follow:

\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = a^{2}(\tau) [ -d\tau^{2} + (\delta_{ij} + h_{ij}) dx^{i} dx^{j}  ] \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Having this perturbed FRW metric, we can plug it into Einstein-Hilbert action and find out the terms which are second order in $h_{ij}$. Now, suppose we have some matter terms such as EM gauge field and inflationary action:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{-1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi \partial_{\nu} \phi - V(\phi) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
This Lagrangian will contribute into the energy-momentum tensor. Then, my question is that how can I find the perturbed energy momentum tensor for gravitational waves in this case?

My difficulty is that if I use tensor perturbation to perturbed $\sqrt{-g} \mathcal{L}$ and expand it into second order in $h_{ij}$, the second order terms may becomes the effective mass term of gravitational waves. However, we know that graviton is massless so the effective mass term should me zero. This part confuse me a lot. If